# Monitor chattr changes

Tags: c, linux

I would like to get notified within a C program, when someone changes a directory or file attributes via command line: chattr.

e.g.:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/test
sudo chattr +i /tmp/test
```

I would like to write a program that detects when /tmp/test directory has become inmutable and reacts to.
I have found inotify, but it will detect only chmod, setxattr... changes, but not chattr.

Comment: Maybe this one helps https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416904/26493

Comment: I wanted something like this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252499/how-to-use-libaudit

Comment: I don't have an answer to your problem, this is why I thought looking at auditctl source helps.

Comment: An option is to program a FUSE driver. It will solve your problems, but it is a hell lot of work. Anyway, may you are interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace shows some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct ev_loop* loop = nullptr;
int fd = 0;
void
sig_handler(int signo)
{
  if (signo == SIGINT)
    printf("received SIGINT\n");
  else if (signo == SIGTERM)
    printf("received SIGTERM\n");
  else if (signo == SIGBUS)
    printf("received SIGBUS\n");
  else if (signo == SIGABRT)
    printf("received SIGABRT\n");
  if (loop != nullptr) {
    std::cout << "Stopping event loop" << std::endl;
    ev_break(EV_A_ EVBREAK_ONE);
  }
}
void
monitoring(struct ev_loop* loop, struct ev_io* io, int revents)
{
  struct audit_reply reply;

  audit_get_reply(fd, &reply, GET_REPLY_NONBLOCKING, 0);

  if (reply.type != AUDIT_EOE && reply.type != AUDIT_PROCTITLE &&
      reply.type != AUDIT_PATH) {
    char* buf = new char[MAX_AUDIT_MESSAGE_LENGTH];

    snprintf(buf,
             MAX_AUDIT_MESSAGE_LENGTH,
             "Type=%s Message=%.*s",
             audit_msg_type_to_name(reply.type),
             reply.len,
             reply.message);

    printf("EVENT: %s\n", buf);
  }
}

int
main()
{
  std::cout << "Starting up..." << std::endl;

  if (signal(SIGINT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("can't catch SIGINT\n");
  }
  if (signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("can't catch SIGTERM\n");
  }
  if (signal(SIGBUS, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("can't catch SIGBUS\n");
  }
  if (signal(SIGABRT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("can't catch SIGABRT\n");
  }

  struct ev_io monitor;
  fd = audit_open();

  audit_set_pid(fd, getpid(), WAIT_YES);
  struct audit_rule_data* rule = new audit_rule_data();

  std::cout << "Add watch dir..." << std::endl;
  audit_add_watch_dir(AUDIT_DIR, &rule, "test");

  // setting rule.
  audit_add_rule_data(fd, rule, AUDIT_FILTER_EXIT, AUDIT_ALWAYS);

  loop = EV_DEFAULT;

  ev_io_init(&monitor, monitoring, fd, EV_READ);

  std::cout << "Enable audit..." << std::endl;
  audit_set_enabled(fd, 1);
  std::cout << "Start io monitor..." << std::endl;
  ev_io_start(loop, &monitor);
  std::cout << "Start event loop..." << std::endl;
  // now wait for events to arrive
  ev_run(loop, 0);
  std::cout << "Closing audit..." << std::endl;
  audit_close(fd);
  delete rule;

  std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```